# Having To Scroll To See Footer

Tags: footer

I am actually kinda new to html, but i cant figure out why i have to scroll to see the footer when there isn't any content between the container and it.

HTML

```
<head>
<!—[if lt IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css" />
<![endif]—>
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">


<!-- end .content --></div>     
<!-- end .container --></div>
    </div>
<div class="footer">
        <p> FOOTER CONTENT </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100%;
    }

.footer {
        background-color: black;
        bottom: 0;
        float: right;
        height: 240px;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 5px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Edit, I added the full HTML body, Please refer to the top HTML section for information.

Comment: can u post the whole html body?

Comment: I tried and got an error saying there was to much code.

Comment: the content of the tags is not relevant. only tags tree

Comment: OK i edited my above post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some malformed html.  It seems to work fine in jsfiddle after stripping everything out before `<body>` and the last `</html>` tag. http://jsfiddle.net/g6gDS/

Edit. I also made the text white in the footer so you can actually see it against the black background.

Comment: Im not quite sure how to fix that.

Comment: Is the link I provided what you expected to see?

Comment: I am not sure. I dont really see what you did minus making the content white.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured part of it out. My body height was set to 100%. So i backed it down to 85% and it eliminates the scroll but there is a black spot of the background showing at the bottom. Hmm